# Coin flipping, chances for second coin being heads

Tags: probability

Imagine the following scenario: I flip a coin $5$ times. I tell you that I got $3$ times heads and $2$ times tails.

From your point of view: What are the chances, that the second throw was heads and why?

- $\frac{1}{2}$ because every flip of a coin is $\frac{1}{2}$ chance to be heads or
- $\frac{3}{5}$ because three out of the five coin flips were heads?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  if, say, you  were told that you got $5$ tails would you think that the probability that the second toss was $H$ is $\frac 12$?

Comment: Your  `every flip of a coin is 1/2 chance to be heads` is only true **>>before<<** the coin is flipped. Afterwards, the outcome is what it is, regardless of that original probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem):

$Prob(2nd=H|3H2T)=\dfrac{Prob(3H2T|2nd=H)P(2nd=H)}{Prob(3H2T)}$

The respective probabilities on the RHS are $\frac{\binom42}{2^4}=\frac6{16}, \frac12, \frac{\binom53}{2^5}=\frac{10}{32}$.

$Prob(2nd=H|3H2T)=\frac{6\cdot \frac12 \cdot32}{16\cdot10}=\frac{3\cdot32}{16\cdot10}=\frac35$